# How do I get the latest blocks of a blockchain in hyperledger fabric in my react component for the hyperledger explorer?

Tags: reactjs, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, explorer

I want to build a new dashboard in hyperledger explorer for a project. My goal is (one of them) to have a horizontal list of blocks without any information. When clicking on a block an information pops up about this block. There should be always five blocks, to be clear: the latest five blocks added to the blockchain in fabric. So if I click on the right block the information about the latest block shows up. The neighbour on the left is the second last block and so on. I already created my blocks and the link in it to the detailed block information. But how do I put in the information about the right blockchain?

Would be great if anyone has an idea, because I'm new to React and don't really know what to do. Just trying out some things and hoping to find a way...
Thanks in advance and regards,
Kathrin

Comment: Can you share code snippet of what you have done?

Comment: `<List horizontal>
 <List.Item>
  <Icon name='cube'  size='huge' data-command="block-link" href="#" onClick={() => this.handleDialogOpenBlockHash(item.blockhash)}/>
 </List.Item>
 <List.Item>
         <Icon name='cube'  size='huge' link=''/>
 </List.Item>
 <List.Item>
  <Icon name='cube'  size='huge' link=''/>
 </List.Item>
 <List.Item>
  <Icon name='cube'  size='huge' link=''/>
 </List.Item>
 <List.Item>
  <Icon name='cube'  size='huge' link=''/>
 </List.Item>
</List></div>  `

Comment: That does not look clear, but I hope you understand. I do have more, but there is not enough space to post it all.
In the links i want to place a dialog with another component (the detailed block information). But I dont know how to put in the information about the correct one and how to get this chart active - like always updated to show the last blocks added.